# jvm forking duplicate child sporadically

Tags: java, jvm

I have one java application which is forking child JVM for doing some execution. Child process looks same like parent one including all arguments.

TO confirm the parent, i verified parent Id and its always original JVM.

Application is running as plain java process i.e. not in any server like apache, weblogic etc.
As processes have same args, both are writing to same log files and open files are too same.

This is new behaviour which was not present earlier. Could someone provide clue around what to check to find cause

JVM version:- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail? How did you observe the child process? What's your java process doing, does it create any threads or call external binaries as @David points out?

Comment: I have setUp alerts to monitor the process which caught up extra running process.
I am not calling something like exec but using many different threadPools.
ThreadPools were there earlier too but started to get issue now

Comment: we were calling tar via Processbuilder which was getting hang at forkAndExec. Fork was successful , so could see java process but not exec.
its getting hang at close syscall for major time

Comment: You can probably add this as an answer so it's easier to spot and I'm pretty sure other people stumble on that occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is an explicit call to `Runtime` [`exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) method.

Something like the following:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec("java -jar myApp.jar");
```

This will create a new process child of the main process.

This can be done explicitly (with the previous code) or implicitly calling some external library that for example start a new process depending on some configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

We were calling tar via Processbuilder which was getting hang at forkAndExec. Fork was successful , so could see java process but not exec. its getting hang at close syscall for major time due to high number of Disk Operations.